# cannot dup2 write end of a pipe to stdout

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe, dup2

i'm having a problem with dup2() and pipe().

i'm receiving EBADF when i try to dup2 a write end of a pipe to STDOUT_FILENO.

i breaked on `dup2(pout[1], STDOUT_FILENO)` with gdb and checked that `/proc/$pid/fdinfo/$pout[1]` has the O_WRONLY flag. this trouble is driving me mad.

> NOTES:
>
> > - at the start of the function i initialize all pipes to -1.
> > - this issue happens only on x86, on my x86_64 workstation everything goes fine.
> > - OS is Gentoo GNU/Linux ( both x86 and x86_64 machines )

```
if(pipe2(pexec, O_CLOEXEC)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: exec pipe: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
  goto start_fail;
}

if(h->have_stdin && pipe(pin)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: input pipe: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
  goto start_fail;
}

if(h->have_stdout && pipe(pout)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: output pipe: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
  goto start_fail;
}

if(h->have_stdout) {
  printf("%s: output pipes: rd=%d wr=%d\n", __func__, pout[0], pout[1]);
}

if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: fork: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
  goto start_fail;
} else if(!pid) {
  // child
  close(pexec[0]);
  close(pin[1]);
  close(pout[0]);

  i= open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);

  if(pin[0] == -1)
    pin[0] = i;
  if(pout[1] == -1)
    pout[1] = i;

  if(h->workdir)
    chdir(h->workdir);

  if(dup2(pin[0], STDIN_FILENO)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: dup2(%d, %d): %s\n", __func__, pin[0], STDIN_FILENO, strerror(errno));
  }
  if(dup2(pout[1], STDOUT_FILENO)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: dup2(%d, %d): %s\n", __func__, pout[1], STDOUT_FILENO, strerror(errno));
  }
#ifdef NDEBUG
  dup2(i, STDERR_FILENO);
#endif

  close(i);
  close(pin[0]);
  close(pout[1]);

  execv(argv[0], argv);
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: execv: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
  write(pexec[1], "!", 1);
  close(pexec[1]);
  exit(-1);
} else {
  // parent
  close(pexec[1]);
  close(pin[0]);
  close(pout[1]);
  if(read(pexec[0],&exec_failed, 1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: exec failed\n", __func__);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    goto start_fail;
  }
#ifndef NDEBUG
  printf("%s: successfully started command '%s' (pid=%d)\n", __func__, argv[0], pid);
#endif
  close(pexec[0]);
}
```

the output is the following:

```
...
handle_cmd_start: output pipes: rd=12 wr=13
...
...
handle_cmd_start: dup2(13, 1): Bad file descriptor
handle_cmd_start: successfully started command 'tools/nmap/nmap' (pid=1154)
....
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dup2` returns the destination file descriptor on success, not zero. Your checks should not be `if (dup2(...))` but `if (dup2(...) < 0)`.

Comment: You have used this style (`if(h->have_stdin && pipe(pin)) ...`) throughout -- and now it bit you in the backside.  If you always explicitly check the error value (1) things like this won't happen, and (2) it will be clearer to the poor sap who follows you.

Comment: @JohnHascall: I think you meant to post that comment on the question, not on this answer.

Comment: dup2 returns -1 on error. The test should be : if (dup2(...) == -1){fprintf(stderr, ...);goto start_fail;}

Comment: Yes, I should have said "**As R.. suggests, you should always check the error value explicitly...**"

Comment: @JohnHascall: I think you're misunderstanding what I said. You seem to be arguing for a matter of coding style. `if (func(...))` is perfectly valid if `func` returns 0 on success, but you're free to disagree as to whether it's good style. `if (dup2(...))` is not valid since the result of `dup2` being zero/nonzero does not tell you whether it succeeded. In general, when in doubt, standard functions return either an explicit -1, or an unspecified negative value, on error. But it's best to check rather than just assuming this.

Comment: @JohnHascall : yep, but by style `if(h->have_stdout && pipe(...)) { error}` fit well with functions that return 0 on success, like pipe does. i thought that dup2 returns 0 on success, but i was wrong. thanks anyway for your suggestion, always appreciated :) .

Comment: Absolutely.  If you write `if (foo()) ...` you really say almost nothing about `foo()` to the next guy (or you 3 years later!).  If `foo()` is super-well known, maybe that's ok, but `if (foo() != NULL)` or `if (foo() != 0)` or `if (foo() > 0)` or (heaven help us) `if (foo()) != 0.0)` tells a lot more.

Comment: No it doesn't. The meaning is identical and purely redundant. Should you write `if (foo()!=0!=0!=0......)`?